# Test and set lock(TSL) are deadlock free?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization

The concept of priority inversion is a case when TSL cannot be deadlock free then how one can say the TSL is deadlock free?

Comment: Please give some background information and elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Lets first look at the definition of Deadlock.

**Definition** :- A set of processes are said to be in **Deadlock**, if they wait for happening of event caused by other processes in the same set. Here the processes in the set are in **waiting/blocked** state.

Now lets understand the **Priority Inversion**. Lets **process A** is a lower priority process running in critical section. and **process B** be higher priority process.

When the **process B** goes to **ready** state,it gets scheduled (goes to **running** state) and  process A gets pre-empted by schedular as it has low priority. Here **Process A** goes to **waiting/blocked** state but it has already locked the critical section and **process B** is in **running** state which then goes in Busy waiting because the critical section is already locked by **process A** !!. This causes an infinite waiting. This case is basically called as **SpinLock** since **process B** is in **running** state and **process A** is in **waiting/blocked** state but according to definition of Deadlock all process should be in **waiting/blocked** state.

This is why TSL is said to be **Deadlock** free but its NOT free from **SpinLock**.

I hope this will be helpful :)